# Setting PHP Storm Live Edit and Compass File watcher

Tags: sass, compass-sass, phpstorm, liveedit

Is there a way to use PHPStorm´s Live Edit and File Watcher together?

I managed to get the File Watcher for Compass and my SCSS files running, Live Edit Plugin also works fine.

But when I change SCSS files and Compass compiled succesfully, Live Edit just don't refresh the site in my Browser.

Is there a solution to get Live Edit running for SCSS files?

Comment: Do you use PhpStorm 7 with the JavaScript Debug configuration to activate Live Edit?